# 5000 characters limit exceeded - Google Apis Explorer

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Using Cloud Text-to-Speech API v1 in Apis Explorer, I get this error when processing larger files: 
5000 characters limit exceeded

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/

I checked my quota in Cloud Text-to-Speech API, the quota of characters in all requests par minute is 150000.

What could I do ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a content limit per request. It is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/quotas). You can send up to 150000 characters in "all requests per minute", but each individual request may contain at most 5000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iterative approach (for/while loop) to process your data. This will limit the number of character at each request.